# Can I Override WebDeploy archive paths through TFS Build?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, webdeploy, automated-deploy

My team is starting to take on the challenge of automating our Build-Deploy-Test process, beginning with the build.

Right now we have Build Definitions configured in TFS that will publish our site to our servers using Web Deploy, and this is working; however, we aren't able to keep an archive of the packages that would be created with each build because when we turn on package creation with the MSBuild parameter `/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=true`, the build fails on silly NTFS file length constraints.

`Exception Message: TF400889: The following path contains more than the allowed 259 characters: \\builds.tfs.company.com\builds\Project.Dev.Nightly\Project.Dev.Nightly_20130630.6\Debug\_PublishedWebsites\Project.Middleware.Service_Package\Archive\Content\C_C\Builds\1005\Project\Project.Dev.Nightly\Sources\Source\Multi\Middleware\Project.Middleware.Service.`

Is there a way that we can break the Archive folder out somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the path by using the _PackageTempDir argument for MSBuild.

Just add `_PackageTempDir=D:\{desired dir structure}` when you're passing in MSBuild arguments.

More full explanation of this property can be found here -

[VS2010 Web Deploy: how to remove absolute paths and automate setAcl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959964/vs2010-web-deploy-how-to-remove-absolute-paths-and-automate-setacl)

Comment: Nice, I look forward to trying this.

Comment: My obj folder still being generated at this long path and my consecutive builds fail because MSBuild can't delete the files located at 260+ characters deeep folder